# Error in R: x must be numeric

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

*i try to write a program in r "generate a random sample from any distribution using function". but it shows "Error in hist.default(xbars) : 'x' must be numeric"
my program is here*

```
sim.clt <- function(n, ran.func,..., simsize,...)
{
  xbars<-vector()
  for(i in 1:simsize=simsize)
  {
    x<-function(ran.func)

      xbars[i]<-mean(x)
 }
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
hist(xbars)
qqnorm(xbars)
return(xbars)
}
sim.out<-sim.clt(n=20,ran.func="rexp",simsize=5000)
shapiro.test(sim.out)
```

## #

i am new in r programming, so can't figure it out, how to solve the problem.
thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of things wrong here.

```
for(i in 1:simsize=simsize)
```

should be throwing an error:

```
> for(i in 1:simsize=simsize) { print(i)}
Error: unexpected '=' in "for(i in 1:simsize="
```

Better is

```
for(i in seq_len(simsize))
```

Then

```
x <- function(ran.func)
```

is not doing what you thought it was; it is returning a function with `xbars[i]<-mean(x)` as its body, as in:

```
> x <- function(ran.func)
+ 
+       xbars[i]<-mean(x)
> x
function(ran.func)

      xbars[i]<-mean(x)
> is.function(x)
[1] TRUE
```

I think you wanted to call `ran.func` so you may need

```
FUN <- match.fun(ran.func)
x <- FUN()
```

But that will fail because you don't seem to be passing any argument for `ran.func` to work, even just `n` in the example using `rexp`.

The error message stems from this last point. You defined `xbars` to be the empty `vector()`, which by default created an empty logical vector:

```
> xbars <- vector()
> xbars
logical(0)
> is.numeric(xbars)
[1] FALSE
```

Now, this wouldn't have been a problem if you hadn't made the error in defining `x` (recall `xbars[i]<-mean(x)` is now in the body of the function `x` and has never been explicitly called), which means `xbars` remains a empty logical vector. As that is not numeric, `hist` throws the error you are seeing.

Another error is that you can't use `...` in the function definition twice. Are you trying to have the first contain arguments to pass to `ran.func` and the second `...` to be for something else. You just can't do that in R.

Is this what you wanted?

```
sim.clt <- function(n, ran.func, simsize, ...) {
  ## ... passed to ran.func for other parameters of distribution
  xbars <- numeric(simsize)
  for(i in seq_len(simsize)) {
    FUN <- match.fun(ran.func)
    x <- FUN(n = n, ...)
    xbars[i] <- mean(x)
  }
  ## plot
  op <- par(mfrow=c(2,1))
  on.exit(op)
  hist(xbars)
  qqnorm(xbars)
  xbars
}

> sim.out<-sim.clt(n=20,ran.func="rexp",simsize=5000)
> shapiro.test(sim.out)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  sim.out
W = 0.9867, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: thanks a lot. that's the thing what i want and your explanation helps me a lot.

Comment: can you give me a suggestion... if i want to modify the function further to not just study the sampling distribution of the mean,  but of any statistic by using second function, what i have to do?

Comment: @moniruzzaman if you have another question, feel free to post it as a separate question. Remember to give a reproducible example and show your code where it fails.